# Java array of array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is what I need in pseudocode:

```
myArray = {
    {Object, Object, Object},
    {Object, Object, Object},
    {Object, Object, Object},
    {Object, Object, Object},
    {Object, Object, Object},
}
```

How can I declare and initialize something like this in real Java?

Comment: The use of 2-dimensional array is often a symptom of a lack of object design and encapsulation. You should probably use a one-dimensional array (or List, or Set) of Triple instances. A Triple being an object encapsulating your three other objects, and providing useful, high-level methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this...

```
Object[][] myArray = {
    {obj11, obj12, obj13},
    {obj21, obj22, obj23},
    {obj31, obj32, obj33},
    {obj41, obj42, obj43},
    {obj51, obj52, obj53},
};
```

Also, see [Oracle's array tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: +1 If `myArray` is declared separately, you need to change this a little bit to: `myArray = new Object[][] { ... };`

Comment: @TedHopp - indeed, a comment worth mentioning